# Major aliens, some good, some bad

Tags: steganography, word-search

Yep, another word search. The title should be a hint...

```
N I B T N S H N O C 
O A U A L O A D A D 
G B I E J P Z R O I 
N R B X M O D A G O 
I V O A A A R N K Z 
L I C M S L E A B A 
K O O S U R A O N T 
U S I B E L R T Y E 
N A O F W G A S P B 
N V U L C A N N P E
```

> There is again a hidden message

I couldn't make it any smaller (10 x 10) and have it still be a square.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the word search solves to:

> [image: Star Trek Word Search]

Where the words are all

> Star Trek races. And the secret message is “It Should Be Obvious By Now”